# sawmill Regular expression pattern

Tags: regex, wildcard, regular-language, wildcard-mapping

I have string with me :

Strings are:

```
"Receiving datame2->$@<CTR>&CTData=<G><TT>d</TT>00<X>Approved</CTR>" **should match**

"Receiving datame2->$@<CTR>&CTData=<G><R>^@^<T>0Y<X>Approved</CTR>" **should not match**
```

I would like to write regex that do match the

```
Receiving datame2(alltextin between)CTR(alldata in between)G(alldata in between)00(rest all data)
```

And .vice verse other then this should be rejected.

can i have to 2 Regular expression 
one for accepting and other one for rejecting the data. Other then this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for matching the first example in your question. The second example will be automatically rejected with the same regular expression.

```
Receiving datame2[^<]+<CTR>[^<]+<G>.+(?=00).+
```

#### Description

[image: Regular expression visualization]

#### Demo

http://regex101.com/r/bE3pZ3